React Native Push Notification stops working after navigating to a different Tab screen
Basically the issue is that - I have a NotificationHandler that registers and handles remote/push notifications. When I render the NotificationHandler outside the NavigationContainer of @react-navigation/native, the NotificationHandler stops working. It registers for Push Notification, but does not receive the notification or display it. However, when I render the NotificationHandler somewhere within the children of NavigationContainer it works! But! It only works unless you switch the tabs, once you switch the tab, the notifications stop showing up.
For the NotificationHandler, the code below uses react-native-notifications@5.1.0, however, for the major part of the development I had been using react-native-push-notification@8.1.1 library.
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import {
  Notification,
  NotificationCompletion,
  Notifications,
  Registered,
  RegistrationError,
} from 'react-native-notifications'

function NotificationHandler() {
  useEffect(() => {
    Notifications.registerRemoteNotifications()
    console.log('NotificationHandler registered')

    Notifications.events().registerRemoteNotificationsRegistered(
      (event: Registered) => {
        // TODO: Send the token to my server so it could send back push notifications...
        console.log('Device Token Received', event.deviceToken)
      }
    )
    Notifications.events().registerRemoteNotificationsRegistrationFailed(
      (event: RegistrationError) => {
        console.error(event)
      }
    )

    Notifications.events().registerNotificationReceivedForeground(
      (
        notification: Notification,
        completion: (response: NotificationCompletion) => void
      ) => {
        console.log('Notification Received - Foreground', notification.payload)

        // Calling completion on iOS with `alert: true` will present the native iOS inApp notification.
        completion({ alert: true, sound: true, badge: false })
      }
    )

    Notifications.events().registerNotificationOpened(
      (notification: Notification, completion: () => void, action: any) => {
        console.log('Notification opened by device user', notification.payload)
        console.log(
          `Notification opened with an action identifier: ${action.identifier} and response text: ${action.text}`
        )
        completion()
      }
    )

    Notifications.events().registerNotificationReceivedBackground(
      (
        notification: Notification,
        completion: (response: NotificationCompletion) => void
      ) => {
        console.log('Notification Received - Background', notification.payload)

        // Calling completion on iOS with `alert: true` will present the native iOS inApp notification.
        completion({ alert: true, sound: true, badge: false })
      }
    )
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [])

  return null
}

export default NotificationHandler

The above is basically straight from the docs, no changes whatsoever.
The NotificationHandler is rendered within the NavigationContainer which has a StackNavigator as the parent screen and a nested TabNavigator within one of the stack screens.
import {
  NavigationContainer,
  createNavigationContainerRef,
} from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Alert, LogBox, Platform, StatusBar } from 'react-native'

import InitialChecksHandler from 'screens/Login/components/InitialChecksHandler'
import Maintenance from 'screens/Maintenance/Maintenance'
import Splash from 'screens/Splash/Splash'

import type { InitialChecksResult, RootStackParamList } from 'utils/types'

import { AUTH_STATUS_MAP } from 'app/constant'

import { useAuthContext } from '../context/AuthContext'
import AuthStackNavigator from '../routes/Auth/Auth'
import MainTabNavigator from '../routes/Main/Main'
import NotificationHandler from './NotificationHandler'

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>()

LogBox.ignoreLogs([
  'Non-serializable values were found in the navigation state',
])

export const navigationRef = createNavigationContainerRef<RootStackParamList>()

// Need to disable type check here
// (Please check the declaration of navigationRef.navigate to understand why)
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
export function navigate(name: any, params: any) {
  if (navigationRef.isReady()) {
    navigationRef.navigate(name, params)
  }
}

function RootRoutes() {
  const { authStatus } = useAuthContext()

  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar backgroundColor="#0090DA" barStyle="light-content" />
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Auth"
        screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
      >
        {authStatus === AUTH_STATUS_MAP.LOGGED_IN ? (
          <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={MainTabNavigator} />
        ) : (
          <Stack.Screen name="Auth" component={AuthStackNavigator} />
        )}
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Maintenance"
          component={Maintenance}
          options={{ headerShown: false }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </>
  )
}

function RootNavigator(): React.JSX.Element {
  const [initialCheckResults, setInitialCheckResults] =
    useState<InitialChecksResult | null>(null)

  if (!initialCheckResults) {
    return <Splash setResults={setInitialCheckResults} />
  }

  return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
      <InitialChecksHandler
        setInitialCheckResults={setInitialCheckResults}
        {...initialCheckResults}
      />
      <NotificationHandler />
      <RootRoutes />
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}

export default RootNavigator

Please let me know if there is need for additional information. Thank you and any help is appreciated since I have been banging my head on this for over a week now.
